# Model with multiple outputs and custom loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to train a model that has multiple outputs and a custom loss function using keras, but I'm getting some error ``` tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over ``tf.Tensor`` is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function. ```

It's hard to debug it because I'm doing `model.compile` and `model.fit`. I think it has something to do with how models are supposed to be defined when having multiple outputs, but I can't find good documentation on this. The guide specifies how to have models with multiple outputs suing the functional API, and has an example for this, but it doesn't clarify how custom loss functions should work when subclassing the `Model` API. My code is as follows:

```
class DeepEnsembles(Model):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DeepEnsembles, self).__init__()

        self.num_models = kwargs.get('num_models')
        model = kwargs.get('model')

        self.mean = [model(**dict(**kwargs)) for _ in range(self.num_models)]

        self.variance = [model(**dict(**kwargs)) for _ in range(self.num_models)]

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        mean_predictions = []
        variance_predictions = []
        for idx in range(self.num_models):
            mean_predictions.append(self.mean[idx](inputs, training=training))
            variance_predictions.append(self.variance[idx](inputs, training=training))
        mean_stack = tf.stack(mean_predictions)
        variance_stack = tf.stack(variance_predictions)

        return mean_stack, variance_stack
```

And where MLP is the following:

```
class MLP(Model):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MLP, self).__init__()

        # Initialization parameters
        self.num_inputs = kwargs.get('num_inputs', 779)
        self.num_outputs = kwargs.get('num_outputs', 1)
        self.hidden_size = kwargs.get('hidden_size', 256)
        self.activation = kwargs.get('activation', 'relu')

        # Optional parameters
        self.p = kwargs.get('p', 0.05)

        self.model = tf.keras.Sequential([
            layers.Dense(self.hidden_size, activation=self.activation, input_shape=(self.num_inputs,)),
            layers.Dropout(self.p),
            layers.Dense(self.hidden_size, activation=self.activation),
            layers.Dropout(self.p),
            layers.Dense(self.num_outputs)
         ])

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        output = self.model(inputs, training=training)
        return output
```

I'm trying to minimize a custom loss function

```
class GaussianNLL(Loss):

    def __init__(self):
        super(GaussianNLL, self).__init__()

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):

        mean, variance = y_pred
        variance = variance + 0.0001
        nll = (tf.math.log(variance) / 2 + ((y_true - mean) ** 2) / (2 * variance))
        nll = tf.math.reduce_mean(nll)
        return nll
```

Finally, this is how I try to train it:

```
    ensembles_params = {'num_models': 5, 'model': MLP, 'p': 0}
    model = DeepEnsembles(**ensembles_params)
    loss_fn = GaussianNLL()
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4)
    epochs = 10000

    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss=loss_fn,
                  metrics=['mse', 'mae'])
    history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                        batch_size=2048,
                        epochs=10000,
                        verbose=0,
                        validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

Which results in the above error. Any pointers? In particular, the whole stack trace is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/emilio/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/emilio/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 2803, in variable_creator_scope
    yield
  File "/home/emilio/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py", line 235, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "/home/emilio/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py", line 593, in _process_training_inputs
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "/home/emilio/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py", line 646, in _process_inputs
    x, y, sample_weight=sample_weights)
  File "/home/emilio/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 2360, in _standardize_user_data
    self._compile_from_inputs(all_inputs, y_input, x, y)
  File "/home/emilio/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 2618, in _compile_from_inputs
    experimental_run_tf_function=self._experimental_run_tf_function)
  File "/home/emilio/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 457, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/emilio/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 446, in compile
    self._compile_weights_loss_and_weighted_metrics()
  File "/home/emilio/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 457, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/emilio/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1592, in _compile_weights_loss_and_weighted_metrics
    self.total_loss = self._prepare_total_loss(masks)
  File "/home/emilio/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1652, in _prepare_total_loss
    per_sample_losses = loss_fn.call(y_true, y_pred)
  File "/home/emilio/fault_detection/tensorflow_code/tf_utils/loss.py", line 13, in call
    mean, variance = y_pred
  File "/home/emilio/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 539, in __iter__
    self._disallow_iteration()
  File "/home/emilio/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 535, in _disallow_iteration
    self._disallow_in_graph_mode("iterating over `tf.Tensor`")
  File "/home/emilio/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 515, in _disallow_in_graph_mode
    " this function with @tf.function.".format(task))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function.
```

So it's clearly related to the loss function. But the model's forward pass outputs a tuple, which I unpack in the loss function, so I don't know why is this an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With quick tests, I think I solved the problem by replacing:

```
        mean, variance = y_pred
        variance = variance + 0.0001
```

With

```
        mean = y_pred[0]
        variance = y_pred[1] + 0.0001
```

Unpacking `y_pred` (which is a Tensor) calls the method `Tensor.__iter__` which apparently yields an error, whereas I suppose that the method `Tensor.__getitem__` does not...

I haven't got to the point when it start learning, I think my current dummy  x_train and y_train are not exactly of correct shape. If you notice that this problem happens again later, I will try to investigate.

EDIT:

I managed to make your code run by using

```
x_train = np.random.random((10000, 779))
y_train = np.random.random ((10000, 1))
```

by changing the last line of the method `DeepEnsembles.call` with

```
        return tf.stack([mean_stack, variance_stack])
```

and by commenting out the metrics (necessary because the sizes of y_true and y_pred are expected to be different, so you might want to define your own versions of mse and mae to use as a metric):

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=loss_fn,
              # metrics=['mse', 'mae']
)
```

I believe it is quite close to what you expect.

The reason for not returning a tuple is that tensorflow will interpret each element of the tuple as an output of the network and will apply the loss independently on each of them.

You can test it by keeping the old version of `DeepEnsembles.call` and instead use

```
y_train_1 = np.random.random ((10000, 1))
y_train_2 = np.random.random ((10000, 1))
y_train = [y_train_1, y_train_2]
```

It will execute, there will be 10 MLP, but MLP_1/2 will learn the mean and variance of y_train_1, MLP_6/7 the mean and var of y_train_2, and all other MLPs will not learn anything.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Inputs should have 779 columns/features and outputs 1 column/feature. Your solution works but I now get the following error: `Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), for inputs ['output_1', 'output_2'] but instead got the following list of 1 arrays:...`

Comment: Can you give me your exact values of `x_train.shape` and `y_train.shape` ?

Comment: The first dimension doesn't matter. So it's [?, 779] and [?, 1] where ? is anything you want.

Comment: Sure, thank you, I managed to make it work (taking 10000 data points, to have multiple batches), please see my edit above.

Comment: how do you know that the rest of the MLP's will not learn anything? Why is this? I would like them to learn.

Comment: If you just change the `return` line in `DeepEnsembles.call` and the instruction `model.compile(...)`, it should work as expected, and you can ignore the end of my answer. It is just an explanation on what tensorflow is trying to do when you return a tuple.